# Blank lines not being removed by regex

Tags: java, linux, command-line, output

I am reading in shell output and displaying it to the console. I am altering

`line`

with

`String test = line.replaceAll("[\\\r\\\n]+","");`

which I believe should be removing all blank lines, but the output does not change.

```
public class tempapp{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String fileName = "temps.txt";
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run(){
                // task goes here

                List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();
                //build command
                commands.add("/usr/bin/sensors");
                //args
                //commands.add("");
                System.out.println(commands);

                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
                pb.directory(new File("/home/ethano"));
                pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
                Process process = null;
                try {
                    process = pb.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //Read output
                StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                String line = null, previous = null;
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        if (!((line = br.readLine()) != null)) break;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (!line.equals(previous)) {
                        previous = line;
                        out.append(line).append('\n');
                        String test = line.replaceAll("[\\\r\\\n]+","");
                        System.out.println(test);
                    }
                }

                //Check result
                try {
                    if (process.waitFor() == 0) {
                        //System.exit(0);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //weird termination
                //System.err.println(commands);
                //System.err.println(out.toString());
                //System.exit(1);
            }
        };

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        long delay = 0;
        long intervalPeriod = 4 * 1000;

        //schedules task to run in interval
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, delay, intervalPeriod);


    }
}
```

Comment: regex should be `("[\\r\\n]+","");`

Comment: You only have a single line in a string without line terminators. If you don't want to write the string to the file, you should check `if(line.isEmpty())`